# DocuSign REST API Carbon copy Incorrect Email

Tags: docusignapi

We are using REST API to create Envelope and Recipients. For Recipient Type 'Carbon Copy' email notifications are generated once envelope is completed which is fine. But, the issue we are having is if the Carbon Copy Recipient has incorrect email address, it doesn't report 'Auto Responded' status, we get the status as "completed" in our connect message for this invalid email Carbon copy recipient. Is it expected docusign behavior or is there a way we can force email validation for Carbon Copy recipients? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you described is accurate for the carbon copy recipient. If you want the auto responded status for bounced emails, you will need the recipient to have an action required (sign, approve, acknowledge receipt, etc).

Comment: Can I add action required feature ( acknowledge receipt) for Carbon copy recipient? if yes, how?  OR are you talking about the certfied delivery type recipient?

Comment: One in the same, acknowledge receipt = certified delivery. Per the answer below, for the certified delivery the recipient must open the envelope in order for their part in the workflow to be marked as completed.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [CertifiedDelivery recipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#certifiedDeliveries). They are like a cc recipient but must acknowledge receipt.